# Bible API for phonegap mobile app

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am developing a mobile app using phonegap for android. I want to integrate the bible with this app. Is there any free Bibile api available which I can freely integrate with my app?

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be [bibles.org Bible API](https://bibles.org/pages/api) which allows you to fetch certain parts of Bible as follows:

> The Bible Search Application Programming Interface (API) allows any developer to include Scripture content and text anywhere in their website or application for non-commercial purposes.

As said there, it is restricted for non-commercial usage.If you need to use it for commercial purposes, see this on same page:

> If you do want to use this content for commercial purposes, you must get specific approval by contacting us via email at support@bibles.org with API in the subject header.

The API itself seems to support XML and JSON so it is ideal for Cordova (Phonegap, that is) app since JSON is easiest format when using JavaScript.